# EFCore навигационное свойство

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf-datagrid, ef-core-3.1

Есть бд OnlineShop в MSSQL. Я эту бд переношу в VS с помощью Scaffold-DbContext. Создаются классы таблиц. Поскольку таблицы в бд OnlineShop имеют связи, то в классах VS образуются навигационные свойства. Я вытягиваю в List переменную эту таблицу, чтобы ее foreach'ем добавить в коллекцию а уже коллекцию вывести в DataGrid. При передаче таблицы в List переменную(Не важно как, делал и Sql запросами и с помощью Linq) также переносится и навигационное свойство.

Как выгрузить таблицу в коллекцию без навигационного свойства?

Таблица Client:

```
  public partial class Client
 {
     public Client()
     {
         Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
     }

     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
     public string Surname { get; set; } = null!;
     public string Patronymic { get; set; } = null!;
     public string Address { get; set; } = null!;
     public decimal PhoneNumber { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }//навигационное свойство
 }
```

Выгрузка таблицы в DataGrid:

```
using (OnlineShopContext db = new OnlineShopContext())
        {
            var collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();//коллекция
            switch (SelectTable.SelectedItem)
            {
                case "Client"://выбираем в ListBox(SelectTable) таблицу Client
                    var Client = db.Clients.ToList();//переносим в List таблицу
                    DataBase.Columns.Clear();
                    if (db.Clients.Any())//Если данные есть в таблице
                    {
                        foreach (var client in Client)
                        {
                            collection.Add(client);//заносим таблицу в коллекцию
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var columnsList = (from t in typeof(Client).GetProperties() select t.Name).ToList();//переносим в переменную колонки таблицы
                        for (int i = 0; i < columnsList.Count-1; i++)
                        {
                            DataBase.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
                            {
                                Header = columnsList[i]//добавляем в DataGrid колонки
                            });
                        }
                    }
DataBase.ItemSource = collection;//переносим таблицу из коллекции в DataGrid
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Когда я таблицу передаю в List переменную:

```
var Client = db.Clients.FromSqlRaw($"Select * From {SelectTable.SelectedItem}").ToList();
```

или

```
var Client = db.Clients.ToList();
```

или

```
var Client = (from client in db.Clients select client).ToList();
```

List переменная начинает имеет такую структуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В которой сам Client содержит таблицу целиком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И элементы Client`а, в которых содержится строка вместе с навигационным свойством "Orders":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как выбрать из такой List переменной таблицу без навигационного свойства или же занести в List переменную таблицу без навигационного свойства?

Comment: Создайте колонки для таблицы вручную в XAML

Comment: Не используйте сущности (entity) в GUI. Содайте класс-модель с нужными свойствами. Проецируйте данные из БД на эту модель.

Comment: И вообще, дайте больше информации. Может у вас ленивая загрузка используется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, есть бд OnlineShop в MSSQL. Я эту бд переношу в VS с помощью Scaffold-DbContext. Создаются классы таблиц. Поскольку таблицы в бд OnlineShop имеют связи, то в классах VS образуются навигационные свойства. Я вытягиваю в List переменную эту таблицу, чтобы ее foreach'ем добавить в коллекцию а уже коллекцию вывести в DataGrid. При передаче таблицы в List переменную(Не важно как, делал и Sql запросами и с помощью Linq) также переносится и навигационное свойство

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Варианты: 1. создайте колонки для таблицы вручную в XAML. 2. создайте класс-модель с нужными свойствами (без навигационного свойства) и мапьте на него. 3. удаляйте ненужную колонку тем или иным образом https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208390/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данную проблему с помощью DTO.